# XSLT Formatting number gives wrong thousand an grouping separator

Tags: xml, xslt, number-formatting

I have an XSLT page, which needs to become regional aware. I pass the thousand and decimal separator by session parameters to my page. I put them in a xsl:decimal-format and try to call it on my amount fields.

```
    <xsl:param name="userNumberFormat"/>
    <xsl:param name="userThousandSeparator"/>
    <xsl:param name="userDecimalSeparator"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format NaN="" decimal-separator="$userDecimalSeparator" grouping-separator="$userThousandSeparator" name="userFormat"/>
    ...
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(Payment:InstructedAmount/System:Amount), '#,###.00', 'userFormat')"/>
```

But I have a problem when I deploy, the characters are wrong formatted.

For example the instructed amount field gets following input:
0.12

My thousand separator is a comma and my decimal separator a dot.

But this gives the output:  00,.

I tested the session variables $userDecimalSeparator and $userThousandSeparator by printing them out on the page hard coded and they get their values correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a variable in any of the `xsl:decimal-format`'s attributes.

Predefine several `xsl:decimal-format` elements, and use a parameter to select one of them by name.

---

### Added example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="decimal-format">EU</xsl:param>

<xsl:decimal-format name="US" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator="," />
<xsl:decimal-format name="EU" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." />
<xsl:variable name="decimal-format-pattern">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$decimal-format='US'">#,###.00</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$decimal-format='EU'">#.###,00</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(1234.567, $decimal-format-pattern, $decimal-format)"/>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will return `1,234.57` when the `num-format` parameter is "US", and `1.234,57` when the parameter is "EU".

Note that the *pattern* argument of the `format-number()` function is interpreted according to the decimal-format in use - so it too must be parametrized.

Comment: Can you give an example, because I'm confused.

Comment: See the added example above.

Answer (score 1):

Two further observations:

(a) your XSLT processor SHOULD give you an error message when you specify `decimal-separator="$userDecimalSeparator"`, since the value is required to be a single character.

(b) XSLT 3.0 allows you to parameterize xsl:decimal-format using shadow attributes, which can be set to the value of a static parameter:

```
<xsl:param name="userThousandSeparator" static="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="userDecimalSeparator" static="yes"/>
<xsl:decimal-format name="userFormat"
   NaN="" 
   _decimal-separator="{$userDecimalSeparator}" 
   _grouping-separator="{$userThousandSeparator}" />
```

Comment: I just hate it when people downvote without explanation. Feedback is welcome, downvoting without explanation gives no useful feedback. Do you think the answer is wrong, or not useful, or unclear, or doesn't meet the SO definition of what constitutes an answer, or what? Which part (a or b) don't you like?

Comment: Upvoted Michael Kay's  answer and comment. I stumbled upon this in 2021 when I was searching for information how decimal-format and format-number are tied together and if it's possible to change from european to english separators (or even space thousands separator for both) dynamically without having to establish an decimal-format for each. This is the first and only mention yet of parameterizing with XSLT 3.0. Doesn't solve my case in terms of making it possible, but still helps me understanding what changed with version 3.0. So yes, Michael's content is valuable, not only in this case.